# Looking for a opensource, web based, double entry accounting system

Tags: lamp, accounting

I need some accounting functionality for an existing web based system and are trying to find an open source web based accounting package with which I can integrate instead of writing the functionality myself. It should preferable be LAMP based. I can be very basic i.e. just a cashbook and general ledger.

Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: This question would be on-topic on Software Recommendations: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a good wiki page covering [open source accounting tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_accounting_software).

Answer (score 0):

Would Tonido be something you were looking for? Tonido incorporates Money Manager EX, but a web based version of MMEX.

http://www.tonido.com/